# How does falling dollar make goods cheaper for foreigners?

Tags: macroeconomics, foreign-exchange

If the exchange rate between the dollar and euro is 1 to 1. Then a 100 million dollar Boeing jet should cost around 100 million euros. If inflation in the US is 5% (0% in Europe), then the Boeing jet would now be 105 million dollars in the US.

So, the dollar would fall 5% (.95 dollars for every euro)to equalize prices and make them equal in both countries. In my example at least, a falling dollar had no benefit, and the falling dollar made the prices equalize (.95 x 105 is around 100). How does falling dollar help, because aren’t prices always equal from purchasing power parity?

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not explain the context/source of your claim

> falling dollar make goods cheaper for foreigners

2. The claim is usually made in a *ceteris paribus* context. If everything else remains unchanged, such a shift in the exchange rate does make US goods relatively cheaper for holders of foreign currency.
3. Your reasoning does not start from a *ceteris paribus* context, but assumes that prices have to remain equal (Law of One Price) and calculates the exchange rate from that. Unsuprisingly, starting from this assumption prices will remain equal.